# using Javascript HTML Formular

Tags: javascript, html, forms, button, onclick

I have mayn different question first and for all there is this pretty normal for who wants to know your firstname and lastname (its German but I hope this deosent matter)

```
<form name="formular" action="" onsubmit="">
<p>
<label for="vorname">Vorname:</label>
<input value="" type="text" name="vorname" id="vorname" size="25">
</p>
<p>
<label for="nachname">Nachname:</label>
<input type="text" name="nachname" id="nachname" size="25">
</p>
    <p><input type="button" value="Absenden" onclick="doFunction();" /></p>
</form>
```

Then i want to use a function who gets the Name from the form and then shows all Names who ever fill out that form like a Guestbook. Until now i just made it to call an alert whon says "Hallo" but i dont even know how to use The form input as Variables.

I hope u can help me, pls only use JS and HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can capture the fields and add them to an array, and then print that array onto the page.
Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kvy10qa9/) containing my code. The existing add button appends to a *ul* element above the form and saves the name to a global array. I added clear and load buttons as well, so that you can see how to populate the list from the array.

```
<ul id="guestList">

</ul>
<form name="formular" action="" onsubmit="">
    <p>
        <label for="vorname">Vorname:</label>
        <input value="" type="text" name="vorname" id="vorname" size="25"/>
    </p>
<p>
    <label for="nachname">Nachname:</label>
    <input type="text" name="nachname" id="nachname" size="25"/>
</p>
<p>
    <input type="button" value="Absenden" onclick="storeVals();" />
    <input type="button" value="Clear List" onclick="clearList();" />
    <input type="button" value="Load List" onclick="loadList();" />
</p>
</form>
```

And javascript:

```
var names = []; //global scope

function storeVals() //declare function to store the input
{
    //document.getElementById finds the element with the 
    //corresponding ID. In this case I'm getting the objects 
    //behind each of the input boxes, and retrieving their value properties 
    //(the text entered in them). I'm also concatenating them together with
    //the plus sign (+) operator, and adding a space between them with the ' '
    //I'm storing the result of all that in a variable called name.
    var name = document.getElementById('vorname').value + ' ' +     document.getElementById('nachname').value;

    //I'm accessing the names array I declared above. The elements in the
    //array are accessed using an index which counts from 0.
    //So to get the first element, I would do names[0].
    //In this case I'm using names.length instead of a number, as it will return
    //the number of elements currently in the array. When there are zero, it will return 0.
    //When there is one, it will return 1, which happens to be the index for the second element.
    //The means I'm always assigning the name to the element after the last existing one.
    names[names.length] = name;
    alert(names); //just to help see what's going on. Remove this when you don't need it anymore.

    //Uses document.getElementById again, this time to get the object behind my ul list.
    //And calls my appendToList function below, passing it my name variable and a 
    //reference to the list object.
    appendToList(name, document.getElementById('guestList')); 
}

function appendToList(name,ulist){
    //this constructs a <li> object and stores it in a variable.
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    //this adds the text of the name inside the <li>
    //so if name is equal to "john smith", I've built:
    //<li>john smith</li>
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(name));
    //adds the li as a child of my existing list object.
    //so:
    //   <ul id="guestList"><li>john smith</li></ul>
    ulist.appendChild(li);
}

function clearList(){
    //gets my ul list object with the id "guestList"
    //sets its innerHTML (all of its contents) to an empty string
    //so regardless of what's inside, it becomes <ul id="guestList"></ul>
    document.getElementById('guestList').innerHTML = '';
}

function loadList(){
    //got my ul list object by id again.
    var list = document.getElementById('guestList');
    //for loop - essentially this means start the variable i at 0
    //keep looping while i < names.length, and increment i by 1
    //each time we iterate through the loop.
    for(i=0;i < names.length; i++){
        //call the appendToList function above, and pass it names[i] and my list object
        //so essentially, loop over every name in the array and call that function with
        //it to add the name to the list.
        appendToList(names[i],list);
    }
}
```

Here are some specific reference materials for some of things I've done.

- [Arrays](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_array.asp)
- [ul DOM object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_ul.asp)
- [the document object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_document.asp)
- [document.getElementById](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp)

But you need to be aware, if you're just using client-side javascript, this data is **not** going to survive a page refresh, and it will not be available if the page is accessed from another browser.

Comment: Thanks a lot but this is a load of code and im new to JS so could u explain what your code does? My most porblems in the MOment are objects and u are using much of them and i dont know how they work in this code.
It would realy helpful. Because copy Paste is one thing, to realy understand it is the other.

Comment: I've added a bunch of comments to explain the code line-by-line. If any of it is confusing, let me know. Also, [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/default.asp) is an excellent resource for all the objects and their functions.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is implement the JavaScript function to get the name. Here's an example:

```js
function doFunction()
{
  var name = document.getElementById('vorname').value;
  alert("hallo " + name);
}
```

```html
<form name="formular" action="" onsubmit="">
<p>
<label for="vorname">Vorname:</label>
<input value="" type="text" name="vorname" id="vorname" size="25">
</p>
<p>
<label for="nachname">Nachname:</label>
<input type="text" name="nachname" id="nachname" size="25">
</p>
    <p><input type="button" value="Absenden" onclick="doFunction();" /></p>
</form>
```

Now you can do something with the name. Maybe you can store it as a global variable like so:

```
var name = "Guest";
function doFunction()
{
  name = document.getElementById('vorname').value;
  //do something here
}
```

And then you change the content of the website on the same page. But you must not navigate from that page; otherwise you may want to use local storage or a server-sided scripting language.